# Json payload is unable to pass to endpoint in wso2

Tags: wso2

here i am passing this payload  `{ "cameraId": "1595", "fromDate": "2021-06-21 09:00:00", "toDate": "2021-06-21 09:00:10", "fileName": "test3" }`
to endpoint directly ,it will give true response as

```
{
"clipUrl": "https://operator.smartkdcl.com/Videodownload/test3.mp4",
"status": true
 }
```

but when i call endpoint from api , it will responds back with false as `

{
"status": false
}`

i tried with payload factory in api to pass this payload to endpoint but still false response.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the scenario that you are trying? Are you using API Manager to expose the API? If yes, can you share the version? Further, can you add the `DISABLE_CHUNKING` common sequence to the respective API and try the scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked , just add  `<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>`
to code ,thank you